# Integration: Why is this wrong?

Tags: definite-integrals

Let $y=x(x-2)^2$.

Solve for $\int {x}$ $dy$ from 0 to $\frac {9}{8}$

It is known that a point, (0.5,1.125) passes through the curve.

This is the original question at part (iv)[image]

We have not learnt how to use substitution in integrals. This is evident usage in method 2:[image]. So, method 2 is not available for us. We used method 1. For method 1, this graph is used to assist to visualised this[image] Where by the purple area is the area to be found and the pink area is the same as the purple area. So, I took the area of rectangle - $\int x(x-2)^2$ from 0 to $\frac {1}{2}$ which got me the answer, $\frac {41}{192}$

[MAIN FOCUS] But speaking about finding purple area, which is the answer to that question, why can't I just do this? Why is this wrong? Note that for this working, the integration is from 0 to $\frac {9}{8}$ I dont know the format for defined integral.

$\int {x}$ $dy$

$=$ $\int {y(y-2)^2}$ $dy$

$=$ $\int {\frac {y^4}{4} - \frac {4y^3}{3} + 2{y^2}}$

$=$ 1.03326416, which is not the same as $\frac {41}{192}$.

Why is this wrong? Isn't this just directly finding the purple area?

An extra note: the original way I wanted to solve this is to make $x$ subject for $y=x(x-2)^2$, however making $x$ the subject.. is extremely tedious. If it is easy, I would have just make $x$ subject and substitute to the equation and solve this immediately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is integrate the function with the limits $0$ and $\frac{1}{2}$ and to subtract it from the rec-tangular with $x$-values $0$ to $\frac{1}{2}$ and $y$-values $0$ to $\frac{9}{8}$. So what you have to calculate is $$\frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{9}{8}-\int_0^{\frac{1}{2}} x(x-2)^2 dx=\frac{41}{192}$$

The area belonging to the desired integral does not go from the $x$-axis to the graph, but from the $y$-axis to the graph.